# Structure for Employee Supervisor hierarchy approval

Tags: java

I want to create a class for employee and supervisor hierarchy for purchase order approval. Here am creating three classes 1) Person Class 2) Employee Class 3) Supervisor class
person class consist of person name, this person will be assigned as employee or supervisor in its employee and supervisor class respectively. The problem comes here when the supervisor also has an supervisor above him, in that can am unable to create the supervisor as employee again. could you please let me know how i can create an approval structure such that even if a supervisor has an supervisor above him he would be able to approve the purchase order.

Thanks & Regards,
Yogesh

Comment: Hint: think interface inheritance, not class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to lay out a class design is to use the "IS A" test.

An employee "IS A" human, therefore the employee class should extend the human class.

A supervisor "IS A" employee, therefore the supervisor class should extend the employee class.

In regards to having a supervisor with a supervisor, the supervisor should be a field in the employee class, this way every employee (And remember a supervisor "IS A" employee) has a supervisor.

Now in your employee class you can have a processPurchase() method that checks with his supervisor, and then in the supervisor class you can override this method so that it doesn't need to check with his supervisor.

If the supervisor needs to check with his supervisor, the class structure would remain the same, however the method would a little different. In the employee's processPurchase() method he would simply ask his supervisor to process it. However, in the supervisor's processPurchase() he would need to check if he has a supervisor, and then act accordingly, so in semi-pseudo-code:

```
public class Supervisor extends Employee {

    //constructor
    public Supervisor(){};

    public processOrder(){
        if(this.getSupervisor() == null){
            //Don't have a supervisor, send out the order
        } else {
            this.getSupervisor().processOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that the Employee class needs to contain the supervisor field and accessor methods, and then the Supervisor class will inherit them

Comment: Hi Ben, The issue is am unable to create purchase order with supervisor user, am able to create it only with the employee user. could you tell me what should be the structure so that the purchase order can also be created from the supervisor user and it further moves to its supervisor for approval.